# Getting Facebook Picture After Authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to automatically get the user's profile picture when authenticating their Facebook

```
addFacebookInformationToProfile() {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      // This will only merge in information the first time, then ignore it once the flag is true
      const user = Meteor.user();
      let username = slugify(user.services.facebook.name, '');
      let i = 1;
      while (Meteor.users.findOne({username})) {
        username = slugify(user.services.facebook.name, '') + '' + i;
        i++;
      }
      Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.userId(), 'profile.facebook': { $ne:true }}, {
        $set: {
          'profile.email': user.services.facebook.email,
          'profile.name': user.services.facebook.name,
          'username': username,
          'profile.gender': user.services.facebook.gender,
          'profile.facebook': true
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

What I have tried is under the

`'profile.gender'` line I put

`'profile.picture': "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large",` When running this line the picture shows like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4nzmhad4pf6dqb/Screenshot%202016-05-13%2015.53.25.png?dl=0

I've also tried `'profile.picture': user.services.facebook.picture,`

Both to no avail, what could show take place after `'profile.picture':`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the facebook picture with:

`"https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture?width=200&height=200",`

Comment: This is what I got when putting that code: [Console Output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w46b00vcss5yhjz/Screenshot%202016-05-13%2016.22.02.png?dl=0) [What the picture shows](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5igkc3xdkp8cllq/Screenshot%202016-05-13%2016.22.29.png?dl=0)

Comment: well your screenshot shows you're not calling the facebook URL but some other stuff in front of it.

Comment: I copied the code here [Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3k50nbk1636w98t/Screenshot%202016-05-13%2016.24.15.png?dl=0)

Comment: what do you mean "type it in your browser"?

Comment: type the URL in your browser. it works. I see a chinese kid there if that's what you want to know. So it's your app lookup of the URL that is messed up: there is extra stuff added in front of the url, so it's likely that you use a 'relative' link in your template. instead of absolute link

Comment: What did you type in the browser? [This is what I got](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ln3cikwd4t6sen/Screenshot%202016-05-13%2016.29.26.png?dl=0)  Could you show me an example of a relative link

Comment: yor console log shows this: http://officialrelyphe.imgix.net/http://facebook.... 
the `http://officialrelyphe.imgix.net/` part must be the hostname, right?

Comment: well, type it in your browser WITH A VALID USER ID ;-)

Comment: How do I delete the prefix of Officialrelyphe.imgix

Comment: how do you call the URL? yo umust be doing something like `<img src='{{profile.facebook.picture}}'>` which should be fine with the https:// in the code. but if you use relative path like <img src="/{{...}"> or your url in front, you will get your host url. 
Is the officialrelyphe.imgix.net your url or your host url? if not then it may be something else.